# How can i make something stay that way after clicking is done?

Tags: javascript, onclick, click, addeventlistener

I have an image which is an arrow for sorting the list. When i click it has to change to other image which is downward of the same image.  But it doesn't stay that way after clicking. . I need if else statement here because i will need the reverse list with new image after first click.
It's not all of my Javascript. I tried to copy the parts which are related to my question. I hope it is an understandable example.

```js
const sorting = document.querySelector('#sortingIcon');
let arr = [];
sorting.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

    if (sorting.src = "images/Group74.png") {
    sorting.src = "images/Group90.png";
    const items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        console.log(items[i])
        arr.push(items[i].firstChild.value);
    }
    arr.sort();
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].firstChild.value = arr[i];
    }
}

})
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div id="yellow"></div>
    <h1>To-do list</h1>

    <img id="sortingIcon" src="images/Group74.png" alt="sorting">

    <div id="inputBox">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="input1">
        <img class="clear" src="images/Group77.png" alt="">
    </div>


    <button id="plus_button">
        <div id="flex">
            <div id="plus">+</div>
            <div id="enter">Добавить </div>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

How can i make it stay that way?

Comment: please share more of your code - can you provide enough HTML and Javascript to make a runnable snippet embedded in your question? The small bit of code you have there should absolutely not revert the image back to the "Group74" one after clicking.

Comment: sure, I just didn't want to make a mess first time. My list is created with javascript , but it is a little long code.Should i share it too?

Comment: thanks, that's a bit better. I made it into a runnable snippet in your question. It's not the easiest to see the issue because of course neither of the image paths your using are valid on SO - but from inspecting the output in the browser, I don't see the problem: I see the source starting as Group74, then changing to Group90 when I click. You do have a typo in your `if` statement - the `=` you have should be `===` (or `==`), and this will likely cause some problems, but it definitely doesn't cause the problem you describe.

Comment: it does change in mine too, but does it stay that way? because in mine it doesn't.  It just happen for the time period of one click.

Comment: there must be some additional code in your real example then. Because when I run your example, click once, and then inspect the HTML later, it shows the new URL.

Comment: Oh, then that must be it. I should go check other parts. Thank you so much for your help. Now i now this part works correctly.